# Mobile device can not be connected to computer to run Apps in Android

Tags: android-studio, adb, kill, restart

Every time when I plug my phone to the computer via USB cable to run my apps in Eclipse or Android studio IDE, it's not possible to execute the apps. And it gives the following error,

> *Android Studio*:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdHpM.png)

Although I tried to kill  and restart adb.exe in "Task-manager" or "command-line" the problem didn't solve. Even I created file restartADB in my sdk path\platform-tool and tried to execute it but I still got this error

> *Eclipse*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp8ih.png)

And it's not possible for me to use Android virtual machine to test my apps

Comment: Did you download the image for the selected virtual device using the package manager ?

Comment: Sky A840s, I tryied with HTC but I have got this problem

Comment: Dummy.....I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Did you download the system image for the device platform using the package manager tool?

Comment: Do you mean "Intel x86 Atom System Image" in SDK ?

Comment: and Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image

Comment: Yeah, you need to download system image for each API level you want to run the virtual devict on

Comment: Oh yes, I downlad these but I still can not resolve this error.Now, I get the error : "Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
8:08:30 AM Connection attempts: 1"

Comment: I honestly don't know what is causing the error for you. But I do recommend you check out genymotion, it is free to use for individual developers and it is really really fast. I am vietnamese by the way :D

Comment: Sax, ban la nguoi VN hả.Làm viết tiếng Anh chi cho mệt.Mình kết nối con Sky A840s nhưng lỗi adb hoài, ko chạy app được.Nếu chạy máy ảo thì máy tính mình yếu quá thường hay treo máy với lại mình không thích chạy máy ảo, bạn biết thì sửa giúp mình nha.Dg gấp để làm đồ án hic hic

Comment: có gì bạn nhắn vô email đi, nhuyvan1106@gmail.com. Nếu bạn xài windows, thì phải tải cái google usb driver từ phần "Extra" trong package manager, sau đó bạn cần cài cái usb driver cho cái điện thoại đó nữa. xem phần hướng dẫn cài đặt thêm cái usb driver cho từng loại máy ở đây [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver)

Comment: Cam' ơn bạn nha.Mình cài lại window luôn rồi và kết nối ngon lành.Những bước như vậy mình làm lâu rồi và xưa giờ vẫn dùng ổn định nhưng không hiểu sao nó giở chứng quá